# Hello I want to make 4 objects move left to right in a loop but my code is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the html code as you can see

```
 <!DOCTYPE>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="clouds">
<img border="0" alt="animated clouds" src="clouds.png" >
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

function loop() {
    $('#clouds').css({right:0});
    $('#clouds').animate ({
        right: '+=1400',
    }, 5000, 'linear', function() {
        loop();
    });
}

loop();
 });
 </script>
 </div>
 <div id="clouds2">
 <img border="0" alt="animated clouds" src="clouds2.png" >
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

function loop() {
    $('#clouds').css({right:0});
    $('#clouds').animate ({
        right: '+=1400',
    }, 5000, 'linear', function() {
        loop();
      });
   }

    loop();
  });

  </script>
 </div>

 </body>


 </html>




#clouds {
position:absolute;
z-index:500;
right:0px;
top:10px;
}


#clouds2{

position:absolute;
z-index:500;
right:0px;
bottom:10px;



 }
```

**and this is css as you can see**
I dont understand whu my second cloud wont move thats the thing thats bugging me

It would really mean a lot if someone helped me figure this out i am really lost...Also you could just tell me where i messed up you dont have to change the code if you feel like it,thank you
!!!

Answer (score 2):

The first error was you gave `$('#clouds')` instead of $('#clouds2'), also the function works great, then eventhough the div adjusts fine, the image remained still, so I added a `float:left` to the `img` tag, which made the image move as expected!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function loop() {
    $('#clouds2').css('right', 0);
    $('#clouds2').animate({
      right: '+=1400',
    }, 5000, 'linear', function() {
      loop();
    });
  }

  loop();

});
```

```css
#clouds {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 500;
  right: 0px;
  top: 10px;
}

#clouds2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 500;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

#clouds2>img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clouds2">
  <img border="0" alt="animated clouds" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the movement / animation of your clouds2 in the second part of the script tag. You are still using

$('#clouds')

instead of

$('#clouds2')

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH IT WORKED,SUCH A DUMB MISTAKE ON MY PART!